# Restrict Create Build Definition permissions in TFS

Tags: tfs, permissions

Is there a way to restrict the ability of a user to create a build definition in TFS 2013/2015? The closest thing I found was for [TFS 2008](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181716(v=vs.90).aspx) which stated that creating a build definition requires the "Administer a build" permission, which seems to be missing from the permissions for 2013. Instead there is a "Administer build permissions" which sounds similar enough. This is on my company's production TFS server and I'm just a developer... so I'd like to know for sure before I make a suggestion, and I'd prefer to NOT need to set up my own TFS server.

Comment: We use TFS 2012 and I know for sure there is ability to restrict creating build definition but not so much editing existing once. Unless you just restrict access to that collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Administer build permissions** is `Can administer the build permissions for other users`. It doesn't control whether a user is able to create a build definition or not.

You need to set **Edit build definition** permission, which is used to control whether a user can create and modify build definitions for this project.

More permission reference, check this article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252587.aspx

Comment: Thank you, it seems obvious now but the list of permissions was kind of confusing. This definitely saved me some time!